# UNUserNotification "NSInternalInconsistencyException", reason 'use +currentNotificationCenter'

Tags: xcode, kivy, unusernotificationcenter

im using kivy to create an IOS project im successfully deployed the IOS project to Xcode. Im trying to implement the UserNotifications framework and im accessing it through pyobjus but when i run the app. it raises this error for some reason and i am already using the instance currentNotificationCenter. if any has an idea on how to debug the code i would appreciate. Here is my code log

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UNUserNotificationCenter init], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UserNotifications_Sim/UserNotifications-281.6/UNUserNotificationCenter.m:66
2020-04-30 01:25:11.610042+0100 pushdemo[2854:117443] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'use +currentNotificationCenter'
*** First throw call stack:
(
   0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c65bf0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c4c79b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
   2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c65bc88 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
   3   Foundation                          0x000000010bea8cd2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
   4   UserNotifications                   0x0000000118c9d4a8 -[UNUserNotificationCenter init] + 172
   5   pushdemo                            0x0000000107122be4 ffi_call_unix64 + 76
   6   ???                                 0x00006000005a0910 0x0 + 105553122167056
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realised its a type method and ive been trying to access it as an instance nethod